# Stack Overflow notification sometimes redirected me to Meta

Tags: discussion, bug

These days when I try to click on Stack Overflow **notifications**, instead of showing me the notifications it's redirecting me to a page called **Meta** or sometimes **Stack Exchange**. Am I the only one who faces this problem with Stack Overflow?

Comment: If the page hasn't fully loaded, clicking the icon will take you to your [global inbox](https://stackexchange.com/users/current). (I am sure there's a dupe for this, but my Google-Fu is failing me.)

Comment: Notification about [your Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418142/208273) will in fact take you to Meta.  Are those the notifications you're referring to?

Comment: No, I agreed with @Larnu said: **If the page hasn't fully loaded, this will occur**

Comment: Hum, "strange"..., I thought Qt's could only be *closed* when the Dup-Target had several Answers or 1 Answer upvoted or accepted, but the Dup-Target for this one has 0 Answer... (Or does a [tag:status-declined] Tag count as a [forced to accept] Answer...?)